# How to include the source set output of one subproject into another?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following project structure where all three subprojects use the `java-library` plugin and the root project only has an `allprojects` block that sets the group and version information.

```
Root project 'project'
+--- Project ':project-a'
+--- Project ':project-b'
+--- Project ':project-c'
```

- `project-a` has no dependencies
- `project-c` depends on `project-a` via `api(project(":project-a"))`
- `project-b` depends on `project-c` (and transitively on `project-a`) via `api(project(":project-c"))`

What I want to achieve is the following:

- When `project-c` is built via the `build` task, the jar file that is procduced should include all classes from

  - `project(":project-a").sourceSets["main"].output`
- Similarly, when `project-b` is built, the jar should include all classes from both

  - `project(":project-a").sourceSets["main"].output` and
  - `project(":project-b").sourceSets["main"].output`

What I've tried is writing

```kotlin
project(":project-c").evaluationDependsOn(":project-a")
project(":project-b").evaluationDependsOn(":project-c")
```

in the root project `build.gradle.kts` and then using

```kotlin
tasks.jar { from(project(":project-a").sourceSets["main"].output) }
```

and

```kotlin
tasks.jar { 
   from(project(":project-a").sourceSets["main"].output) 
   from(project(":project-c").sourceSets["main"].output) 
}
```

in `project-c`'s and `project-b`'s `build.gradle.kts`, respectively.

While this solution works, it feels pretty hacky. From my current understandig this should somehow be possible using Gradle configurations. So, my question is if there is any better way to achieve what I want to do?

**EDIT:**

After some reading, I've realised that the calls to `evaluationDependsOn` are not necessary if configuring the `jar` task is done lazily as was done in this example (and described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors)).

Comment: Are you trying to make a 'fat jar'? You can try the [Gradle Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow). I will note that 'fat jars' [are not best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43287555/4161471) - but if it works for you, then it works. It's more 'correct' to publish all the project artifacts separately though and expose them using `api(...)` (as you have done).

Comment: @aSemy Yes, I was thinking about creating a fat-jar but after giving it some more thought, I agree with you that it's probably not a good idea. I also had the Shadow plugin in mind at first but didn't want to add any additional tasks to my build, hence my question.

Comment: Is there an issue with additional tasks, or is it a preference? Back to your original question: Instead of multiple subprojects you could create multiple sourcesets, and link them together. [The Kotlin Multiplatform plugin is good for this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-share-on-platforms.html) - you can create arbitrary sourcesets and set dependencies, but it can be very complicated.